# How to order imports with tslint's import-ordering rule

Tags: import, tslint

On my project tslint's "import-ordering" rule is used

```
import CopyLensModal from './CopyLensModal';
import FetchStatus from '../../../../../state/generic/models/FetchStatus';
import FlexRow from '../../../../generic/components/FlexRow';
import Geofilter from '../../../../../state/geofilter/models/Geofilter';
import Input from '../../../../generic/components/Input';

import * as React from 'react';
import * as salert from 'sweetalert';

import { func } from '../../../../../types/func';
import { Iterable } from 'immutable';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

tslint is not happy with this order and crashes with error

> [2, 1]: Import sources within a group must be alphabetized.
>   [4, 1]: Import sources within a group must be alphabetized.

[This page](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/ordered-imports/) didn't help that much, I've tried to place imports in many different ways but without luck. Which order will be correct?

Comment: There are a number of configurable options for the `ordered-imports` rule. Without including your rule configuration, this question isn't really answerable.

Comment: "ordered-imports": [true],

Comment: Not as bad as the rule that prevents the I prefix for interfaces, but it's certainly a mean-spirited implementation.

Comment: I wonder - what is this rule good for?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I agree that it's confusing. The problem is that the source string comparisons include the `../..` portions of the module names, so to appease the rule, you would need to sort them like this:

```
import FetchStatus   from '../../../../../state/generic/models/FetchStatus';
import Geofilter     from '../../../../../state/geofilter/models/Geofilter';
import FlexRow       from '../../../../generic/components/FlexRow';
import Input         from '../../../../generic/components/Input';
import CopyLensModal from './CopyLensModal';
```

The rule has two parts and can be configured to enforce orderings of the import names and sources separately. To enforce only the ordering of names only, you could use a configuration like this:

```
"ordered-imports": [true, {
  "import-sources-order": "any",
  "named-imports-order": "case-insensitive"
}]
```

That would raise an error for imports like this:

```
import { A, C, B } from 'some-module';
```

but wouldn't enforce ordering for the module paths, etc.

Comment: Thank you! So confusing. I thought I'd lost my grip on the alphabet for a moment

Comment: Note there is also a `module-source-path` which can be set to `basename` instead of the default `full` option. This would ignore the `../..` portions.

Comment: If you use VSCode and TS 2.8, you can utilize the [Organize Imports](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/03/27/announcing-typescript-2-8/#organize-imports) to easily sort and clean your imports :)

Comment: All the time I was trying to make the order work, I was thinking there must be a way to make this automatic. Thank you @kyw

Comment: @kyw looks like it does not work for "within a group" for example all node_modules imports group, and my own files import group. Any solution for this inbuilt?

Answer (score 16):

This error also happens if there is not empty new line added as separation between groups of imports.

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as os from 'os';

import * as bar from './bar';
import * as foo from './foo';
```

Also notice if the error says like this:

```
***(5,1): Import sources within a group must be alphabetized.***
```

This means in the specified file go to line #5 and press enter to add a new empty line there as separator.

I did that and this resolved my problem. For more reference about this issue review this [page](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/771)

Comment: Got ```Imports from this module are not allowed in this group.``` because of the new line issue. Fixed by adding a new line between the groups

Answer (score 1):

In file `tslint.json` add

```
  "rules": {
    "ordered-imports": [false],
    "object-literal-sort-keys": [false]
  }
```

For example, then file `tslint.json` will look like this

```
{
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended",
    "tslint-react",
    "tslint-config-prettier"
  ],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "config/**/*.js",
      "node_modules/**/*.ts",
      "coverage/lcov-report/*.js"
    ]
  },
  "rules": {
    "ordered-imports": [false],
    "object-literal-sort-keys": [false]
  }
}
```

Comment: Also don'f for get to restart the frontend server. I was not able to see changes while hot-reloading.

Comment: Because everything changing what outside directory `app`, need restarting for the change has effective.