# tslint - Import sources within a group must be alphabetized

Tags: typescript, tslint

I am using a `create-react-app` setup with `custom-react-scripts-ts`.

This is my component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./App.css"; // reset.css

import ErrorsContainer from "./components/Error/Container";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import { initStores } from "./stores";
import { Provider } from "mobx-react";
import typography from "./utils/typography";

// font styles
typography.injectStyles();

class App extends React.Component {
  public onErrorDismiss = () => {
    return null;
  };

  public render() {
    return (
      <Provider {...initStores()}>
        <div className="App">
          <Header foo="string" />
          <ErrorsContainer />
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is the failed to compile error I am getting:

> (7,1): Import sources within a group must be alphabetized.

This is the `tslint.json` file I am using:

```
{
  "extends": ["tslint:recommended", "tslint-react", "tslint-config-prettier"],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "config/**/*.js",
      "node_modules/**/*.ts",
      "coverage/lcov-report/*.js"
    ]
  },
  "rules": {
    "interface-name": [true, "never-prefix"]
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell the order of the imports is OK. Why is this failing to compile?

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41841149/7977208 for a more complete answer

You may try to override the rule by adding this to your tslint rules object.

```
"ordered-imports": [true, {
   "import-sources-order": "any",
   "named-imports-order": "case-insensitive"
}]
```

or alternatively, move the import on line 7

```
import { Provider } from "mobx-react";
```

to the bottom of the import group, which should appease the rule

```
import ErrorsContainer from "./components/Error/Container";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import { initStores } from "./stores";
import typography from "./utils/typography";
import { Provider } from "mobx-react";
```

Alphabetically, in this context,  '.'  comes before 'm'.

Depending on your editor, there's probably an extension available to automatically sort your import statements for you.

Comment: I thought I was supposed to alphabetize module names, not import paths...thanks

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič did this answer now work out? I saw this the question was reset to unanswered.

Comment: For some reason the imports in your answer do not satisfy the ruling. I also tried both vscode extensions with different settings and none worked. Ended up disabling the rule, probably a weird edge case, but still cant accept the answer that does not have a working solution...

Comment: @ehavener thanks, as you said I found the typescript extension for VScode